# Imaginary part of a product of N complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the general formula for the imaginary part of a product of $N$ complex variables?

To be specific, let $a_j, b_j$ be real numbers, then what is
$$
\Im \left(\prod_{j=1}^N (a_j+ib_j)\right)
$$
For $N=2$ it’s simply the sum cross terms and for $N=3$ there’s one $b_j$ multiplying two $a_j$ subject to permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$ as well as the term with all $b_j$. So it seems like neglecting minus signs it’s a sum of terms that permute amongst $\{1,2,…,N\}$ with an odd number of $b_j$. If $N$ is odd then there will be a term with all $b_j$.

What is the general form in a compact expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply it out, and use the fact that $i^k=\begin{cases}1,&\text{ if }k\equiv 0\pmod 4,
\\i,&\text{ if }k\equiv 1\pmod 4,
\\-1,&\text{ if }k\equiv 2\pmod 4,
\\-i,&\text{ if }k\equiv 3\pmod 4,\end{cases}$

to see that

$\boxed{\begin{align}\Im \left(\prod_{j=1}^N (a_j+ib_j)\right) &= \sum_{\substack{X\subseteq \lbrace 1,\dots,N\rbrace}
\\\;\,\lvert X \rvert\text{ is odd}} \left((-1)^{\frac{\lvert X \rvert-1}{2}}\prod_{j\not\in X}a_j \prod_{j\in X}b_j\right)
\\&=\sum_{\substack{\;X\subseteq \lbrace 1,\dots,N\rbrace}
\\\lvert X \rvert\equiv 1 \!\pmod{\!4}} \left(\prod_{j\not\in X}a_j \prod_{j\in X}b_j\right)\quad-\sum_{\substack{\;X\subseteq \lbrace 1,\dots,N\rbrace}
\\\lvert X \rvert\equiv 3 \!\pmod{\!4}} \left(\prod_{j\not\in X}a_j \prod_{j\in X}b_j\right).
\end{align}}$

Here $\lvert X \rvert$ denotes the cardinality of $X.$

---

By the way, here's a similar formula for the real part:

\begin{align}\Re \left(\prod_{j=1}^N (a_j+ib_j)\right) &= \sum_{\substack{X\subseteq \lbrace 1,\dots,N\rbrace}
\\\;\lvert X \rvert\text{ is even}} \left((-1)^{\frac{\lvert X \rvert}{2}}\prod_{j\not\in X}a_j \prod_{j\in X}b_j\right)
\\&=\sum_{\substack{\;X\subseteq \lbrace 1,\dots,N\rbrace}
\\\lvert X \rvert\equiv 0 \!\pmod{\!4}} \left(\prod_{j\not\in X}a_j \prod_{j\in X}b_j\right)\quad-\sum_{\substack{\;X\subseteq \lbrace 1,\dots,N\rbrace}
\\\lvert X \rvert\equiv 2 \!\pmod{\!4}} \left(\prod_{j\not\in X}a_j \prod_{j\in X}b_j\right).
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Using Euler's formula, when $\text{z}_\text{n}\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$\text{z}_\text{n}=\left|\text{z}_\text{n}\right|e^{\left(\arg(\text{z}_\text{n})+2\pi k_\text{n}\right)i}=\left|\text{z}_\text{n}\right|\cos\left(\arg(\text{z}_\text{n})+2\pi k_\text{n}\right)+\left|\text{z}_\text{n}\right|\sin\left(\arg(\text{z}_\text{n})+2\pi k_\text{n}\right)i$$
Where $|\text{z}_\text{n}|=\sqrt{\Re^2[\text{z}_\text{n}]+\Im^2[\text{z}_\text{n}]}$, $\arg(\text{z}_\text{n})$ is the complex arugment of $\text{z}_\text{n}$ and $k_\text{n}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So:

$$\Im\left[\prod_{\text{a}=\text{n}}^{\text{M}}\text{z}_\text{a}\right]=\Im\left[\prod_{\text{a}=\text{n}}^{\text{M}}\left(\Re[\text{z}_\text{a}]+\Im[\text{z}_\text{a}]i\right)\right]=\Im\left(\text{z}_\text{n}\times\text{z}_\text{n+1}\times\dots\times\text{z}_\text{M}\right)=$$
$$\Im\left(\left|\text{z}_\text{n}\right|e^{\left(\arg(\text{z}_\text{n})+2\pi k_\text{n}\right)i}\times \left|\text{z}_{\text{n}+1}\right|e^{\left(\arg(\text{z}_{\text{n}+1})+2\pi k_{\text{n}+1}\right)i}\times\dots\times\left|\text{z}_\text{M}\right|e^{\left(\arg(\text{z}_\text{M})+2\pi k_\text{M}\right)i}\right)=$$
$$\left|\text{z}_\text{n}\right|\left|\text{z}_{\text{n}+1}\right|\times\dots\times\left|\text{z}_\text{M}\right|\times\sin\left(\arg(\text{z}_\text{n})+2\pi k_\text{n}+\arg(\text{z}_{\text{n}+1})+2\pi k_{\text{n}+1}+\dots+\arg(\text{z}_\text{M})+2\pi k_\text{M}\right)=$$
$$\left|\text{z}_\text{n}\right|\left|\text{z}_{\text{n}+1}\right|\times\dots\times\left|\text{z}_\text{M}\right|\sin\left(\arg(\text{z}_\text{n})+\arg(\text{z}_{\text{n}+1})+\dots+\arg(\text{z}_\text{M})\right)$$

So, we get:

$$\color{red}{\Im\left[\prod_{\text{a}=\text{n}}^{\text{M}}\text{z}_\text{a}\right]=\left|\text{z}_\text{n}\right|\left|\text{z}_{\text{n}+1}\right|\times\dots\times\left|\text{z}_\text{M}\right|\sin\left(\arg(\text{z}_\text{n})+\arg(\text{z}_{\text{n}+1})+\dots+\arg(\text{z}_\text{M})\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your complex numbers from rectangular to polar and then use [Euler's Formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to get it in the form $r*e^{i\theta}$. From there, the formula is then:

$$e^{i*k}*\prod_{l=1}^N r_l$$
where $k=\sum_{l=1}^N \theta_l \mod 2\pi$.

Comment: .... and as those angles can pretty much add up to anything I don't see any way the predict or calculate these from the a+bi forms.  So far as I can figure this is the only way to do it.

Comment: You should be able to convert every complex number from rectangular form to polar/exponential form. The conversion itself will give you the angles.

Comment: Yes, of course.  I'm saying that by *only* considering the rectangular format it is clearly not posible to predict what the imaginary term will be as the a and b can contribute to any angle.  This is as opposed to trying to predict a coefficient of a polynomial which to some extent the influence of individual terms *can* be measured.

Comment: You can still use the rectangular format, but you would have to replace $i$ with $x$, and then add up all the powers of $x$ with a remainder of one when divided by four and subtract all the powers of $x$ with a remainder of three when divided by four. Basically, use $i^{4n+k}=i^k$, where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: The formula in this answer, $e^{ik} \prod_{l=1}^N r_l,$ where $k=\sum_{l=1}^N \theta_l \operatorname{mod} 2\pi,$ isn't the formula for the imaginary part of the product, which is what the OP asked for.  The imaginary part is $(\sin k)\prod_{l=1}^N r_l.$  (By the way, you can simply define $k$ to be $\sum_{l=1}^N \theta_l,$ without the $\operatorname{mod} 2\pi$ part; doing that won't change the result.)